# Swift Delegate not being called to close a UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have a CenterViewController which contains a Game Controller. I want to add/remove a RulesViewController that the user can easily refer to as they play.

The RulesViewController appears and is dismissed fine. But the delegate.continueGame method is never called. I've added the protocol to RulesViewController. I've added a class extension to CenterViewController to handle the delegate. What am I missing?? Any help much appreciated...

```
Class CenterViewController: UIViewController {

private var controller: GameController

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
  controller = GameController()    
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
// add all the views here
let gameView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight))
    self.view.addSubview(gameView)
    controller.gameView = gameView
}

// method called when rules button on the gameView is pressed
func showRulesForLevel () {
    let rulesViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RulesViewController") as! RulesViewController
    presentViewController(rulesViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

// extension to the Class to handle the delegate
extension CenterViewController: RulesViewControllerDelegate {

//func to continue the game
func continueGame() {
    controller.gameView.userInteractionEnabled = true
}
}
```

In the RulesViewController I have:

```
protocol RulesViewControllerDelegate {
func continueGame()
}

class RulesViewController: UIViewController {

var delegate: RulesViewControllerDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

// code to add a continue button which when pressed calls continueGameAction method 
}

func continueGameAction() {
    // dismiss the UIViewController so game can continue
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    // continue the game in CenterViewController
    delegate?.continueGame()
}
}
```

BUT delegate?.continueGame() is never called.

Comment: I think you have to set the delegate ;) rulesViewController.delegate = self in showRulesForLevel method :)

Comment: very many thanks sloik! That one has had me stumped for a few hours.... Thanks A lot!

Comment: Cool :) I have added an answer could you mark it as 'right' one ;) Thx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so you need to set the delegate in `showRulesForLevel` method like this:

```
rulesViewController.delegate = self
```

:)